# Can we update the genesis head wasm after obtaining a slot?

Tags: parachain, wasm, genesis

I have some confusion regarding WASM genesis state. I'm not entirely sure what it contains or how to update it once we've acquired a slot.

For some context: assume we have a substrate based chain that is doing a hard fork to a parachain. We saved the substrate chain's information into a JSON file for the genesis block. This is intended to the the genesis block for the parachain.

Upon bidding for a parachain slot, we generated and uploaded a WASM genesis file (without writing the previous chain's account information into the chain_spec.rs) for the sake of bidding on the auction and registering the parachain. The question is this: do we need to update this WASM genesis file if we intend to use the genesis block JSON file we generated prior to starting our lease? Additionally, if we do need to update the WASM genesis file, is it only through a forceful update using `paras->forceNewHead`?

Thanks all in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no way that your chain will produce blocks with the WASM and Genesis you registered on chain, then the only way to push new WASM and Gensis is through the Relay Chain Governance. Would be a similar situation to [this one](https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/motion/317).

On the other hand, if your chain is producing blocks, then you can use different extrinsics on your own parachain (upgrading it, setting storage, etc) to update your state/code.